# Overlapping image with background image that has navbar and logo

Tags: html, css, sass

[How do I stack images on bg-image exactly like this using html there is a navbar and logo on the BG as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrHvb.jpg)

i tried something like this

```
// clearfix
.image-stack::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.image-stack__item--top {
    float: left;
    width: 66%;
    margin-right: -100%;
    padding-top: 15%; // arbitrary
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.image-stack__item--bottom {
    float: right;
    width: 75%;
}
```

it didnt work as anticipated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOYzQ.jpg)

Comment: show us your html view

Comment: <div class="image-stack">
<div class="bg">
    <div class="image-stack__item image-stack__item--top">
      <img src="">
    </div>
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this.
But first you need to understand
[CSS Positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp), CSS Layout (Using [Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) / [FlexBox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) / [Float](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp), etc ) & [CSS BoxModel](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

So based on the snippet you posted, I am going with float, but I would have recommended flex as it's powerful and flexible.

Below is what I came up with.

```css
/* USING MOBILE-FIRST APPROACH, I.E DEFINING CSS FOR MOBILE FIRST  */

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* Will serve as container */

.image-stack {
  position: relative;
}

.image-stack .bg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* overlay-color */
  background: black;
}

.image-stack .bg>img {
  opacity: .75;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


/* will serve as row */

.image-stack .image-stack__item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.col-half {
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.text-format {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.text-format h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.img-overlap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


/* RESPONSIVE CSS FOR BIG DEVICES */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .image-stack {
    background: yellow;
    /* height must be set in vh, px, rem, em  */
    height: 80vh;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }
  .col-half {
    /* SINCE WE ARE NOT USING `box-sizing: border-box` WE HAVE TO REMOVE THE LEFT AND RIGHT PADDING WE GIVE FROM MOBILE CSS = (20PX) FROM THE WIDTH   */
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
    float: left;
  }
  .text-format {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .img-overlap {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image-stack">
  <div class="bg">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1045/1440/400">
  </div>
  <div class="image-stack__item">
    <div class="col-half text-format">
      <p>5th Consistent Award Winning Year!</p>
      <h1>Modern Design Solutions</h1>
      <p>A descriptive paragraph that tells clients how good you are and proves that you are the best choice.</p>
      <p>A descriptive paragraph that tells clients how good you are and proves that you are the best choice.</p>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn">See our Projects</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-half">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1008/600/400" class="img-overlap" alt="Overlapping Image" />
    </div>
    <!-- Notice Break that I used to clear float -->
    <br clear="both" />

  </div>
</div>

<div style="background: brown">
  Other test
</div>
```

I added comments in the css section to guide you.

CodePen Link => https://jsfiddle.net/d5urpbL2/17/

Comment: Thank you, this method works.
I have now learned flexbox as well, trying to improve on that